# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \left( 0.5 \right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How to find the sum of the following series:
>
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n \left( 0.5 \right)^n$$

Comment: [This post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn) might help.

Comment: @DavidMitra Might help? There is a solution there!

Comment: Why the downvote

Comment: @DavidMitra, thank you for the link.

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}(0.5)&+(0.5)^2&+(0.5)^3+\cdots\\
&+(0.5)^2&+(0.5)^3+\cdots\\&&+(0.5)^3+\cdots\end{align}$$

Comment: Then I'll end up summing $2 + (2- 0.5) + (2-0.5-0.5^2) ...$. I don't see how that became easier.

Comment: Look again.  The first row is 1, the second is 1/2, the third is 1/4...

Comment: Actually, I looked in the answers from the link provided by Mr.Mitra and now I understand what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$S = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} n(0.5)^n$$
$$S = 0 + 0.5 + 2*(0.5)^2 + 3*(0.5)^3 ....$$
$$0.5S = 0 + (0.5)^2 + 2*(0.5)^3  + 3*(0.5)^4 ....$$
$$S - 0.5S = 0 + 0.5 + (0.5)^2 + (0.5)^3 ...$$
As you can recall, this is the sum of an infinite geometric series with $r = \frac{1}{2}$. So $$0.5S = \frac{0.5}{1-0.5}$$
$$S = 2$$

Answer (score 3):

We know that (from generating functions or geometric series):
$$
\frac 1{1-x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k
$$
differentiating both sides:
$$
\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k
$$
Now subtracting and setting $x=\frac 12$:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty k\left(\frac 12\right)^k = \frac 1{\left(1-\frac 12\right)^2}-\frac 1{1-\frac 12}=4-2=2
$$